# How can I restore proper encoding of 4 byte emoji characters that have been stored in plain utf8 - like this: ðŸ˜Š?

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, emoji

Is it possible to re-encode emoji 3 or 4 byte strings into emoji again?

I inherited a MySQL Innodb table with utf8_unicode_ci encoding. These emoji 4 byte strings are everywhere. Is it possible to translate them back into emoji?

First step was to modify the `character set` to `utf8mb4`.  This changed all strings like `ð��£` to strings like this: `ðŸ˜Š`.

But what I really want is to translate `ðŸ˜Š` into something like [image: smiley emoji]. (I have no idea if `ðŸ˜Š` is really a smiley)

Comment: What “4-bit characters” are you talking about? And what do you mean by translating emoji into emoji? This looks like a character encoding mismatch. Show some actual data (hex dump or something else that gives the real data – “�” is REPLACEMENT CHARACTER indicating character-level data error, without telling what the data is).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: [Emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) are outside the BMP, which means that you need 4 bytes (not bits) in order to encode them as UTF-8.

Comment: I modified the collation to utf8mb4 and now the replacement characters look like `ðŸ˜Š`.  But I'm still unsure how to see the actual emoji character.

Comment: @Ignacio *Some* (well, ok, *most*) emoji are outside the BMP, but some are inside as well. For instance ⛄. 

Comment: @Ryan Changing the column from `utf8` to `utf8mb4` after the fact doesn't necessarily help. If you tried to store characters outside the BMP inside a `utf8` column, the data is already irreparably broken. We'd need more details about the original data to say if anything can be done. And "ðŸ˜Š" is not a smiley, "ðŸ˜Š" is "ðŸ˜Š". If the encoding was handled correctly a   would be a .

Comment: I think changing the charset of the column may have damaged the text...
`>>> print u'\xf0\x9f\x98\xa3'`
`ð£`
`>>> print u'\xf0\x9f\x98\xa3'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`
``

Comment: @deceze, that makes sense. In what situation would this be reparable? How can I determine if it's possible to convert ðŸ˜Š into [emoji]? The previous encoding was `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: I suppose you'd need to write a parser or use some text parsing tool to output known combinations 2 byte chars combinations to 4 byte chars ('ab'+'cd' = 'abcd'). You probably want to employ a lookup table to find the known values. Of course you need to store the output appropriately.

Comment: In theory, never ever use any other encoding anywhere other than normal UTF8. Never transcode anything anywhere and you should be fine. UTF8 ist variable length and supports as many bytes as needed! (I never tryed emoji though) Your problem might be that somwhere, you change your encoding (maybe even unknowingly) or send wrong headers.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108312#comment29995421_20108312). Next python code snippet shows origin procedure [Emoji](http://getemoji.com/) to [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) and vice versa (repair):

```
print ( "\nEmoji to mojibake (origin):")
for emojiChar in ['','','','']:
    print ( emojiChar, emojiChar.encode('utf8').decode('cp1252'))

print ( "\nmojibake to Emoji (repair):")
for mojibakeString in ['ðŸ˜Š','ðŸ˜£','ðŸ‘½','ðŸ˜Ž','ðŸ™‡']:
    print ( mojibakeString, mojibakeString.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8'))
```

I *know* that the question is tagged [**php**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) rather than *python*; let me hope that analogous *php* solution could be very close…

**Output**:

```
==> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

==> D:\test\Python\20108312.py

Emoji to mojibake (origin):
 ðŸ˜Š
 ðŸ˜£
 ðŸ‘½
 ðŸ˜Ž

mojibake to Emoji (repair):
ðŸ˜Š 
ðŸ˜£ 
ðŸ‘½ 
ðŸ˜Ž 
ðŸ™‡ 

==>
```

Python version:

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Answer (score 0):

The majority of Emoji requires 21-bits, which is part of the [Supplementary Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane).  Per the chart on that page, Emoji is prefixed with `1F`, spanning `1F3` to `1F7`.  If your application simply stripped the top 5 bits to fit into 16-bits, you would have been left with 3xxx -> 7xxx.  This mostly maps to Asian ideographs per this information on the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).  Given the data you are showing is not ideographs, you may have to analyze the data more deeply to see if it is recoverable by recombining the bits together and adding the `1F` prefix.