# Is there a way to recover a clinking beer emoji from CP1258 text encoding?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, emoji

I have this emoji '' (U+1F37B). I have its plaintext when encoded into CP1258 which is "ðŸ»". I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108312/how-can-i-restore-proper-encoding-of-4-byte-emoji-characters-that-have-been-stor) question for how to change the encoding properly. I tried to follow this same exact procedure for "ðŸ»" but it just crashed the program. Is there any way to reliably do this without just creating a dictionary with "ðŸ»" as the key and '' as the value? Examples in Java, Python, C# or Javascript appreciated :)

Edit: This is what Notepad++ made of it. Not sure what it means: [image: Notepad++ emoji]

Comment: How exactly did you manage to encode it in CP1258 in the first place?

Comment: I didn't. I got this by exporting my messages from Facebook (who seem to be on a mission to make this as difficult as possible). I know this is that emoji by accessing that message from the actual app. I know the encoding simply by testing a bunch of encodings and seeing which is the same.

Comment: Are you sure you're not simply looking at a UTF-8 encoded file using the wrong encoding? How exactly have you exported from Facebook, and how exactly have you "tested a bunch and saw which are the same"?

Comment: A primer on encodings might help to get you onto the same page: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: @deceze I put  into http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx and tried every format. Windows-1258 matched what I got from the text that Facebook gave me. I exported from Facebook with this procedure: https://www.facebook.com/help/131112897028467

Comment: That Facebook link doesn't work [for me] and your matching exercise is, pardon, useless. Get a hex editor and look at your file in hex, see what that emoji is actually encoded as in binary (hex).

Comment: How does that help? The two results in hex (and binary) vary significantly. However, I know what Facebook gave me was the  emoji. Isn't clear that it's Win-1258 - otherwise why would they result in the same thing?

Comment: Imma go with: your file is actually UTF-8 encoded and all you need to do is open it in an editor that actually treats the file as UTF-8. Alternatively, a UTF-8 → CP12xx conversion has taken place at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrong, it's not displaying in CP1258, it's CP1252. The bytes you're getting are UTF-8 encoded, and one of them can't be displayed - there are 4 bytes, not 3. Here's some Python:

```
>>> '\U0001f37b'.encode('utf-8')
b'\xf0\x9f\x8d\xbb'
>>> '\U0001f37b'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1258','ignore')
'đŸ»'
>>> '\U0001f37b'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252','ignore')
'ðŸ»'
```

Recovering the emoji character is simply a matter of decoding those bytes again:

```
>>> '\U0001f37b'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8','ignore')
'\U0001f37b'
```

Comment: Is the 4th byte the character that looks like "RI" from notepad++?

Comment: @BenCooper not sure, I don't have notepad++. It seems plausible though.

Comment: Also, why can a character sometimes not be displayed?

Comment: @BenCooper sometimes the character just isn't in the font being used. In the case of CP1252, that byte code `8d` isn't defined as any character at all.